# Merging Data in columns from one dataframe into a more condensed version

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a csv file which I want to chart using matplotlib. The data set I have needs some updates before I can make this viable from a charting perspective.

For example my data looks like this;

```
state   |county |candidate  |party  |total_votes_x  |won

> 0 |Delaware   |Kent County    |Joe Biden  |DEM    |44552  |TRUE
> 1 |Delaware   |Kent County    |Donald Trump   |REP    |41009  |FALSE
> 2 |Delaware   |Kent County    |Jo Jorgensen   |LIB    |1044   |FALSE
> 3 |Delaware   |Kent County    |Howie Hawkins  |GRN    |420    |FALSE
> 4 |Delaware   |New Castle County  |Joe Biden  |DEM    |195034 |TRUE
> 5 |Delaware   |New Castle County  |Donald Trump   |REP    |88364  |FALSE
> 6 |Delaware   |New Castle County  |Jo Jorgensen   |LIB    |2953   |FALSE
> 7 |Delaware   |New Castle County  |Howie Hawkins  |GRN    |1282   |FALSE
> 8 |Delaware   |Sussex County  |Donald Trump   |REP    |71230  |TRUE
> 9 |Delaware   |Sussex County  |Joe Biden  |DEM    |56682  |FALSE
> 10    |Delaware   |Sussex County  |Jo Jorgensen   |LIB    |1003   |FALSE
> 11    |Delaware   |Sussex County  |Howie Hawkins  |GRN    |437    |FALSE
```

I want to create a dataframe based on this csv file - president_state.csv that has combined all the votes based on the value in the candidate column per state (ignoring the county breakdown), end result looks something like this;

[image]

To add the new column I can use;

```
df = pd.read_csv('president_county_candidate.csv')
new_column = pd.DataFrame({'total party votes': []})
```

In the case of some states there will be quite a large number of counties but I would love to understand where to start to get this data in to python.

The code I am using to plot my chart is;

```
df = pd.read_csv('president_county_candidate.csv', index_col=0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = df.sort_values('total_votes', ascending=False)
ax.bar(df.index, df['total_votes'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=60, horizontalalignment = 'right', fontsize = '12')
ax.set_title('2020 Election', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("#Votes")
```

The idea will be to make this a stacked bar chart indicating party votes within the overall total for each state - now it just returns the total vote per state.

Comment: looks like a simple groupby to me. Can you post your data here instead of a picture so other people can replicate it easier?

Comment: I have added my data - I had to wrap in code tags as I could not get the table format to work for me.

Comment: I have added my data - I had to wrap in code tags as I could not get the table format to work for me.